# how do i add a value to the top of an array in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

how do i add a value to the top of an array in mongodb?

say i have this document in my mongo collection:

```
{ "colors" : [ "red", "green", "blue" ] }
```

how do i add "yellow" to the front of the list?

when i do:

```
{$push:{colors:"yellow"}}
```

i'd get this:

```
{ "colors" : [ "red", "green", "blue", "yellow" ] }
```

i want this:

```
{ "colors" : [ "yellow", "red", "green", "blue"] }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey @conman, can you please change the accepted answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"unshift" inserts data in the front of an array.. whereas "push" inserts it at the end.
e.g. in JavaScript:

```
> a = ['red','green','blue']
[ "red", "green", "blue" ]
> a.unshift("yellow")
4
> a
[ "yellow", "red", "green", "blue" ]
```

But unfortunately this isn't supported by the Mongo API as an atomic operation:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

it just supports "push"

---

**How big is your array?**

you could ether assume that your array in Mongo is always stored in reverse, and use push, or you could read-out the array, modify it with unshift, and then store it again (which wouldn't be atomic though)

Comment: i don't believe mongodb supports the unshift modifier. i did this:db.testarray.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("4df7a9e469408e69b19abd08")},{$unshift:{colors:"pink"}}). and got this error: Invalid modifier specified $unshift.

Comment: Yeah, that's how implemented it temporarily. Taking out the whole array, adding elements to the top, then storing it back in. But as you mentioned, it's nolonger atomic. I guess the other suggestion would work. I just have to read it in reverse. I was hoping mongodb provided a native way of doing inserts to the top. Thanks for the suggestion! Oh and the array can grow pretty big. Depending on the user. There's no set limit.

Comment: the 10gen team is pretty open to suggestions when it comes to improvements of MongoDB.. you could try to put this in as a feature-request for the API

Comment: yeah, i think i'll do that. just wanted to make sure i wasn't missing a feature in the api. thanks guys!

Comment: There is a feature request: [SERVER-2362](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2362)

Comment: Now it's supported. Since v2.5.3, you can use the `$push - $each - $position: 0` syntax, which is awkward. Please help [implement $unshift by voting on this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19974).

Comment: down-voting an answer just because it's now supported is not very cool

Comment: This is not a javaScript question. He is asking about a MongoDb feature and mongoDb doesn't have a feature such as $unshift

Answer (score 35):

For anybody new to this, MongoDB 2.6+ supports the [`$position` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/), which can be used to achieve the desired effect. The benefit here being that you don't need to return your entire document array, update it locally and save it - the `$position` operator means things can be done atomically.

You need to use it in conjunction with `$each`:

```
$push: { colors: { $each: ['yellow'], $position: 0 } }
```

Comment: The `$push - $each - $position: 0` syntax is awkward. Please help [implement $unshift by voting on this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19974).

Comment: thanks for your workaround. It do agree we could use $unshift, but this does the trick for now.

Answer (score 0):

A alternative way to do unshift an object is push() then reverse(). I am not sure whether this will work you if you plan to maintain the original sequence.