# Add values to the beginning of an array with mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How would I go about atomically adding a value to the beginning of an array in mongo?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/7936019

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i add a value to the top of an array in mongodb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936019/how-do-i-add-a-value-to-the-top-of-an-array-in-mongodb)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [can you have mongo $push prepend instead of append?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131957/can-you-have-mongo-push-prepend-instead-of-append)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly as per [this ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2362).

Your only option is for now is to fetch the array, put the element at the beginning and put it in mongo again.

Comment: Now you can. Since v2.5.3, you can use the `$push - $each - $position: 0` syntax, which is awkward. Please help [implement $unshift by voting on this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19974).

Comment: @DanDascalescu I'd post it as an answer.

Comment: This question is a duplicate and should be closed. Posting an answer to questions I had marked as duplicates had earned me some ire on Meta.

Answer (score -3):

```
someArray.unshift(someValue);
```

E.g.

```
> x = [1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
> x.unshift(0)
4
> x
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: i dont think mongo has $unshift