# Mongoose unshift findAndUpdateById

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What's, if there is, the correct way to *`unshift`* a value into a Mongoose document's array through `findByIdAndUpdate`?

I tried this which doesn't give error but also doesn't seem to update the value

```
Schema.findById(id, function(err, doc){
    console.log(doc.array.length); // => 1
    Schema.findByIdAndUpdate(id, 
        { array: { unshift: { property: 'value' } } }, 
        { upsert: true },
        function(err, doc) { 
            console.log(doc.array.length); // Also => 1
        }
    );
});
```

`$push` works. `$unshift` gives the error

> ```
> [MongoError: exception: Unknown modifier: $unshift
> ```

[Docs say to use `unshift` instead](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/migration.html#arrays), but it doesn't work. Or am I using it wrong? It doesn't give any error, just doesn't update the array..

Answer (score 3):

[Found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936019/how-do-i-add-a-value-to-the-top-of-an-array-in-mongodb/25732817#25732817) that the [**`$position`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) operator  in conjunction with `$each` works with `$push` to achieve the same.

```
{ array: { $push: { property: {$each: ['value'], $position: 0 } } } },
```