# unshift operation on MongoDB array using Mongo functions vs. Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB 3.0 (for clarity, not 3.2) and I want to unshift an object to an array. My main schema is `client` which has a sub-schema of `opportunities` and under that another sub-schema of `opportunitiesUpdates`.

My object, and therefore the array in the `opportunities` sub-schema, contains text and number fields as well as other objects.

Opportunities schema:

```
var opportunitiesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // removed other fields for bevity
  updates: [opportunitiesUpdates]
});
```

OpportunitiesUpdates schema:

```
var opportunitiesUpdates = new mongoose.Schema({
  by: {
    userName: String,
    realName: String
  },
  when: {type: Date, default: null},
  description: String
});
```

I'm using Mongoose 4.x as my ODM.

My existing code is:

```
Client.findOne(
  {'_id': { $in: [clientId] }, 'opportunities._id': { $in: [opportunityId] }},
  function(err, client){
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json(err);
    } else {
      var opportunity = _.find(client.get('opportunities'), function(o){
        return o._id == opportunityId
      }); // _.find
      opportunity.updates.unshift(body); // body is escaped req.body
      client.save(function(err){
        return res.status(200).json(client);
      }); // client.save
    } // if
  } // function
); // Client.findOne
```

Vars `clientId`, `opportunityid` and `body` are all defined before. This code works fine and makes the right updates.  The right Client document is found, the correct opportunity document is located in the array thanks to lodash's `.find`, the update is unshifted to the `updates` array, and then it's saved.

**But** this is not one atomic transaction where MongoDB locks the collection while making the change, completes the whole change (the unshift) in one tranaction leaving the document in the final desired state.

There is one transaction where the document is found (`.findOne`) and then some calculations are made, the document updated, and then it's saved back (`.save`) as a second transaction.

Is there any way I can do this with a single MongoDB transaction? Else where I use `.findOneAndUpdate` with `$push` or `$set` but I can't seem to make this work here. I've looked at [28360526](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360526/mongoose-unshift-findandupdatebyid) and [7936019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936019/how-do-i-add-a-value-to-the-top-of-an-array-in-mongodb) but can't make this work the way I want - `$each` and `$position: 0` looks like it should do the business but it just overwrites the whole array with the contents of the object rather than unshifting.

Performance isn't critical here as there aren't that many updates made to an opportunity so a few extra ms for processing time isn't key, what is key is atomicity and avoiding risk of race conditions.

Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Comment: Which array? I don't see any array in the sample structure at the top of the question. You seem to be trying to act on something called `"opportunities"`, but your schema does not have such a field present. Wrong schema perhaps? It would be better to show a sample document you want to modify anyway.

Comment: Neil, right, I've edited with more details on the schemas. The issue here is the fact that it's a sub-document of a sub-document so the $ operator only works on the first level down, not two levels down. The opportunities sub-documents are similarly stored in an array under the clientSchema (which Mongoose compiles to an object Client).

Comment: I think you should show a document from your `Client` model's collection here. The other schema details are also clearly not relevant. Show the document and what you intend to add.

Comment: Neil, surely the OpportunitiesUpdates schema above shows the data types etc. of what is to be unshifted. The Client model/schema has dozens of fields of different types, none bar one of which are relevant to opportunities - that being opportunities: [opportunitiesSchema].  As I say, this code is working perfectly, my issue is not about schemas, nesting, data or anything - just solely the atomicity of the transactions and getting from a multi-step process to a single transaction. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Third and last time. You are acting on `Client` yes? So all anyone wants to see is where this array fits into the context of that document. You still have not done that, so "clear as mud" as the saying goes. Your question gives no input other than "not working", so if you cannot show the correct context  ( which is what a "document" that you are trying to update looks like in structure ) then you cannot get input as to what you are doing incorrectly which is causing it "not to work". I'm not sitting at your desk and neither is anyone else. All we can see is what is in your question. Not enough

Comment: It is working - not the way I want, but it is working. Yes the compiled model is `Client`. An example document of what I'm trying to unshift to the `updates` array would be `{by: {userName: 'Neil', realName: 'Neil Lunn'}, when: '2016-04-05 12:00', description: 'an update'}`. This would be unshifted to the array in the field name `updates`.  This array exists in the `opportunitiesSchema`.  Opportunities are sub-documents stored in a field named `opportunities` which is an array.  One client can have multiple opportunities and each opportunity can have multiple updates. Does that help explain?